# How a TextView never go out of the screen if the user scroll Down?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I'm a android intermediate developer and I need someone expirence to do a trick in my content activity;

this is my content Activity:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  ....
 // How this TextView never go out of the screen if the user scroll Down
  <TextView ... />  
  ....
</ScrollView>
```

*What I did :

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView ... android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    ....
  // 
 <TextView ...android:visibility="visible"/>
  ....
  </ScrollView>
 </FrameLayout>
```

I thought about having 2 TextView, one Invisible in the top and the other visible. 
When the user scroll down and before the second TextView will be gone I set the first textView visible.

is it a good way ? if so how to do it ?

Comment: Can you please explain your Question in more detail.Thanks

Comment: @M'hamed : Quite simply, don't put the `TextView` inside the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="VISIBLE EVERY TIME"
        android:visibility="visible" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" >
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yeah I know .. But that not what I wanna do ...the textView is in the scrollview but never get out !

Comment: What do you mean by never get out ?

Comment: the idea is to uses a synchronized scrolling technique to take a certain view from inside the ScrollView content and let it float to the top of the screen when it would have otherwise been scrolled off-screen. take a look to the last response if you are curious ... Thank you Salman :)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the TextView outside of the scrollView. ie.

```
<LinearLayout> 
<EditText /> 
    <LinearLayout> 
       <ScrollView></ScrollView>  
    </LinearLayout> 
</Linearlayout>
```

Give this a try sorry for the format

Comment: but that's the trick :D
to have the textview inside the scrollview but never go out..
Is there any way to track the scrollView position ?